# mongodb cursor's forEach does not execute

Tags: mongodb, meteor-blaze

I have this code

```
var employeesEdited = [];
var employees =  Employees.find({group: 'ABC', task : { $in: ['CHANNEL MANAGER','SUPERVISOR','LINE LEADER'] }}
                    , {employeeNo: 1, firstName: 1, middleName: 1, lastName: 1, task: 1, supEmpNo: 1, supName: 1});

console.log(employees.count()); // I get 0 on this

employees.forEach((employee) => {
    console.log('inside for each'); // this does not run, no logs in browser
    employeesEdited.push(employee.employeeNo, employee.supEmpNo, 'test_tooltip');
});

employees.forEach((employee) => {
    console.log(`Emp no: ${employee.employeeNo}`);
});

console.log(employeesEdited);
```

What I am trying to do is to loop through the returned cursor of my collection using for each. But it doesn't appear to execute. The console.log inside the forEach loop does not execute.

Also the Cursor.count() method returns 0.

BUT when I console.log the returned cursor from the find function, I can see that there are items in that object if I console.log(employees)

Not really sure what I am doing wrong here, I followed the syntax as per documentation in meteor.

Also I changed the code from using function() to using the fat arrow but still the same results

This code is inside the Template.template.onRendered event. Other codes run, but this forEach is not working for me.

SAMPLE Document

```
{
    "_id": "5b27c83b4e6a6cb37b141910",
    "employeeNo": "RMM090713",
    "prodClientGroup": "ASC",
    "prodDivision": "DCS",
    "prodChannel": "ABC",
    "prodSection": "ADMIN",
    "prodTeam": "TEAM 1",
    "prodProduct": "",
    "prodClassification": "TEST CLASSIFICATION",
    "lastName": "SANTOS",
    "firstName": "MARK",
    "middleName": "MENDOZA"
}
```

I made the schema very simple and flat, 1 row of data is for 1 document.

Comment: can you post a sample data from employees collection?

Comment: This looks like a faulty query rather than an issue with `cursor.forEach`. Please add the document(s) you expected to be returned by your collection, a @Astro already commented.

Comment: I have added the sample document from mongodb

Comment: I tried to do the forEach operation on a sample project from a tutorial and it actually works. You gave me some ideas so I checked the structure of the object in chrome developer tools but they appear to be of same structure

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cursor.toArray((err,docs)=>{})` instead of `cursor.forEach`.

Comment: same result, it won't execute the block code of toArray()

Comment: what is the version of mongo driver?

Comment: it says 1.4.2, I haven't touched this. this is what the create new project command set